# XML Schema context type inside a sequence

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xsd, schema

I am creating an XML Schema using C# but I have found a rather odd sequence of tags that I have never worked with before it. I want it to look something like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Sensor_Info">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Sensor" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:complexType>   
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="location_id" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="unit" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="min_value" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="max_value" type="xsd:int"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:attribute name="count" type="xsd:int"/>
```

I appriciate if you can help me thanks :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am using C# to create this schema and I can't figure out how to include a complex type inside a sequence like the one above

Comment: When you say you are creating a schema using C#, what exactly do you mean? And what difficulty are you hitting?

Answer (score 0):

Your best friend is MSDN... I am showing below an adapted sample from the [XmlSchema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation page; basically, chain your SOM API calls the same way as your XSD structure.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

class XMLSchemaExamples
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        XmlSchema schema = new XmlSchema();

        var ct = new XmlSchemaComplexType {Name = "Sensor_Info"};
        schema.Items.Add(ct);

        var at = new XmlSchemaAttribute
        {
            Name = "count",
            SchemaTypeName = new XmlQualifiedName("int", XmlSchema.Namespace)
        };
        ct.Attributes.Add(at);

        var seq = new XmlSchemaSequence();
        ct.Particle = seq;

        var sensor = new XmlSchemaElement {Name = "Sensor", MaxOccursString = "unbounded"};
        seq.Items.Add(sensor);
        var sensorType = new XmlSchemaComplexType();
        sensor.SchemaType = sensorType;

        at = new XmlSchemaAttribute
        {
            Name = "id",
            SchemaTypeName = new XmlQualifiedName("string", XmlSchema.Namespace)
        };
        sensorType.Attributes.Add(at);
        // TODO add more attributes here

        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationCallbackOne;
        schemaSet.Add(schema);
        schemaSet.Compile();

        var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        schema.Write(Console.Out, nsmgr);
    }

    public static void ValidationCallbackOne(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
    }
}
```